# JS Date to ISO String Strange behavior

Tags: javascript, date

```
new Date("2018-09-9").toISOString()
```

This gives `2018-09-09T04:00:00.000Z`

Where as

```
new Date("2018-09-19").toISOString()
```

Gives `"2018-09-19T00:00:00.000Z"`

I am from US so `4:00:00` seems correct UTC time,  but if I give any date greater than 9 it gives `00:00:00` am I missing anything?

Comment: What happens if you put “09” instead of “9”?

Comment: In first statement your date is not in proper format it should be "yyyy-mm-dd" not "yyyy-mm-d" that is what creating the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a correct behaviour. See the Reference for Javacript Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> **Note:** parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

Your second version is using the format ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD` which is treated as UTC. If you use `2018-09-09` instead of `2018-09-9` in your first example it will also be treated as UTC instead of local time.